# Migrate sharepoint database from SQL Server 2012 R2 evaluation to SQL Server 2012 Standard

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server-2012

My sharepoint is using SQL Server 2012 R2 Express as a database Server, and I already have reached the limit of 10GB. However I have a SQL Server 2012 Standard with proper license.

Would it be possible to install my SQL Server Std on the same server in order to limit the database size limit?

Can I install my SQL Server 2012 Std on the same server I have of my SQL Server R2?
Is there any risk doing that in terms of SharePoint compatibility?

NOTE: I ended up installing SQL Server Std 2012 on same server, however the db size limit still persists... is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

for me, if you are trying to move the database from Sql Server express 2012 R2 to Sql Server 2012 Standard(Without R2), then it is big No.
SQL Server database files are never backwards compatible - if you create a database on SQL Server 2012 express R2 - there is no way, no hack, no trick, no method to get this to be able to be restored or attached on an earlier version of SQL Server.

I think your best option is rebuild the farm using the new SQL server to avoid any issue.

But another thing you can try,

- Create site collections in newly created Sql Server instances, then move the data from old sites to new site.
- Once your data completely migrated then you can delete the old sites(from Express instances).
- But your Config will be remain on the express server but will be fine because config db never grow that big.

another solution to move the data are 3rd part tool.

Answer (score 0):

You now have two instances of SQL running.  Your databases are still on your SQL Express instance.  You will need to move them to your Standard instance and configure SharePoint to look for that instance instead of the Express instance.  Microsoft has some documentation about moving all databases from one SQL server to another (or instance to instance).  See [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.15%29.aspx).